# Can we pass an object as an argument to a decorator function?

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

I have been working on with decorators quite a while now , and have seen them in action in Django REST Framework (@api_view), and also In some of my own code. As for the definition and usage part I am clear that how it works.
But I am interested to know if I can pass on an Object as argument to a Decorator.Also if we cannot then why we can't?

```
@my_decorator(my_object)
def my_func():
    return something
```

Comment: i am talking about objects not fucntion

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to do that? Everything in Python is an object, so if you can pass an argument, you can pass any object.

Comment: I thought a function was an object...

Comment: A function _is_ an object. That's why you can pass it as an argument to a decorator. Just like classes, modules, etc.

Comment: can you explain me by example

Comment: @AtulJain Maybe this question would help you, I think it's close to what you are asking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292239/python-functions-are-objects